# How much time mail kit required to update the changes created by the user in fetching result?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I want to know, How much time mail kit required to update the changes created by the user in fetching result. Because i am not able to get the changes same time while fetching from mail kit. Is there any way to sync mail kit with actual mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think anyone understands your question because it doesn't make much sense, but I will speculate that what you are *trying* to ask is:

> How long does it take before the IMAP server notifies the client that changes have occurred to the mailbox (such as a new message being added or an existing message being expunged) or to a message (such as flag changes)?

The answer to that is server-dependent and not related to MailKit at all.

Comment: Thanks, But I have some confusion If I am using Gmail and I make some changes in my account then I open the same account in another browser, Same changes are reflected at a time so why not in MailKit?

Comment: The browser doesn't use IMAP, so that's not a good comparison. MailKit will only emit the event(s) when the IMAP server (GMail) sends those events. Obviously, GMail did not send those events.